# WebLogic Server fails to make secured connection to the Target URL with SSLHandshake exception

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic12c

I have a java application which is hosted using WebLogic 12c managed server. It is calling an external API end point which is secured.
This is an outbound connection from weblogic server to target server, for example, https://www.demosite.com/api/end/point. Initially as I got the SSLHandshake error.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I imported Certificate of the target server "https://www.demosite.com" into the CustomTrust.jks keystore in my weblogic managed server. Also imported the same cert into JAVA Default keystore cacerts.

With this I started seeing successful api calls. But this was not consistent. Seeing intermittent failures very often. So I decided to add below java argument to my managed server startup settings.

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

Managed server restarts are done by deleting Managed_Server tmp & cache folders.
This action item did not help to fix the problem. Then made some changes to the SSL configuration in the weblogic managed server settings. Like below ones,

Hostname Verification: Custom Hostname verifier
Custom Hostname Verifier: weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier
Use Server Certs: Checked
Two Way Client Cert Behavior: Client Certs Requested But Not Enforced

None of the settings I tried did not help to fix the issue completely.

From Jdeveloper integrated weblogic server in my local machine the API call never fails. Only in weblogic managed server running on the Linux Server is giving this problem. In my local machine I did not import target server certs explicitly. What Am I missing here? Target allows only TLSv1.2/SSLv3 connection.

Comment: *"Seeing intermittent failures very often. So I decided ...."* - this information does not help. You don't provide the actual error you get, only "intermittent failures". And then you fiddle around with settings which likely have nothing to do with the error. Unfortunately we cannot help here since it is unclear what error you actually have.

Comment: Also it is extremely unlikely any server today allows SSLv3, which has been broken and prohibited by practically everybody since 2015. It is fairly common, and good practice, to allow only (aka require) TLS 1.2 or 1.3 -- or equivalently TLS >= 1.2. However the protocol version makes no difference to the certificate validity, nor vice versa.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich
Apologies for not providing error stack. I mean I'm getting SSLHandshake errors sometime after importing certificate. Before importing cert it was 100% failure.

<Sep 30, 2023 3:41:07,303 PM EDT> <Error> <com.demo.application.microservice.testing.rest.resource.v1.TestResource> <BEA-000000> <
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: @Subbu: if the same client (your WebLogic server) with the same configuration (i.e. trust store) and in the same network setup is sometimes able to verify the target server with this trust store and sometimes not than there is likely something unexpected with the target server, i.e. it is sometimes sending the certificate + chain you expect and sometimes not. This might for example happen if their are multiple servers for the same domain with different IP addresses and configuration.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 
Even I suspected same but from the local weblogic setup it has 100% pass rate. Target server is Microsoft Graph API calls. Anything that might be blocking at network level?

Comment: What does it matter what pass rate the local weblogic setup has if this is about communicating with some remote server? It is not even clear what is even tested. And there is nothing "blocking". If there would be something blocking, then you would get a connection error not a certificate problem.

Comment: This is resolved. Found that I was suppose to install only the root and intermediate certificate in the JKS keystore or java default cacerts. It doesn't require the target Server certificate.

Answer (score -1):

This is resolved. Found that I was suppose to install only the root and intermediate certificate in the JKS keystore or java default cacerts, I was missing the Intermediate Cert in my keystore. It did not require the target Server certificate.